# httpURLConnection makes my application stop

Tags: android, connection, httpurlconnection

Hi everyone hope you doing well
I have a problem with my application,I'm using of below code for connect to some address(as you see here its my local address) My problem is when I shutdown my wamp server or for example if my application could not connect to address that I gave it before,my application stops after a special time and it gives me an error.
I'd like to know how can I change my code to when application could not find address(for any reasons),my application gives a message to user Instead Of Keep stops.how can I handle that?

here is my code

```
String json_url = "http://10.0.2.2/ss/1.php";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void...voids){
        try{
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while((json_string=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(json_string+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Deal With Wrong Address");
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks For All Your Help.

Comment: Did the below answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

First You should check if your application has Internet connectivity, then only you call this method.

```
 ConnectivityManager connMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = connMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
// Do stuff here for API call
}
```

Once you have called you can further catch timeout Exceptions and show custom msg in your try catch

Add following catch blocks

```
        }catch (SocketTimeoutException bug) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException bug) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Also set connectionTimeout parameter as well for your request using -

```
httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000); // 5 sec timeout
```

Comment: @AmirAlizadehHesari What's the issue now? do you get any errors

Answer (score 0):

Guys I think I've fixed that 
All I needed was this line

```
return String.valueOf(0);
```

Instead of

```
return null;
```

but many thanks to kapsym